# What is the role of SHA-1 on Diffie-Hellman-group1-SHA1?

Tags: diffie-hellman, sha-256, sha-1

I undersntand that in **Diffie Hellman** each party generates a public / private key pair and distributes the public key.
I know that a combined key is created with the sender private key, and the receiver public key.
Is SHA used when the combined key is created?

Answer (score 2):

Big picture is: the hash is used to turn the "combined key" of the question into symmetric keys used in a protocol. That's useful because the "combined key" is not a uniformly random bitstring, and because multiple keys with no exploitable dependence are needed.

---

Quoting [RFC4253](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253#section-8.1):

> The "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" method specifies the Diffie-Hellman key exchange with SHA-1 as HASH, and Oakley Group 2 [RFC2409] (1024-bit MODP Group). (…) Note that this method is named using the phrase "group1", even though it specifies the use of Oakley Group 2.

Looking at [RFC2409](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2409), it designates the "combined key" of the question as "the Diffie-Hellman shared secret" and notes it `g^xy`. It designates SHA-1 as `SHA`, with reference to [FIPS 180-1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/FIPS/fipspub180-1.pdf) so that's not SHA(-0). It uses it for construction of a Pseudo-Random Function noted `prf`:

> If a "`prf`" is not negotiat(ed), the HMAC version of the negotiated hash algorithm is used as a pseudo-random function.

[HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is a Message Authentication Code built from a hash (using the Merkle–Damgård construction, or otherwise with a natural message block length), and that hash is going to be SHA-1, which has 64-byte block length and 20-byte output.

RFC2409's PRF is noted `prf(key, msg)`. The absence of length tells that when instantiated as HMAC it always outputs the hash's full width, thus 20 bytes for SHA-1.

I fail to make full sense of the details of the many things that RFC2409 prescribes to do with it's `prf(key, msg)`. Slightly confusingly, `g^xy` enters the `msg` input, and only gets to the `key` input indirectly. I think this is to accommodate PRFs with a size restriction on `key` (which does not exist in HMAC).

---

Note: SHA-1 is seriously broken, though not when used in HMAC with a secret key (or in the ways RFC4253 uses it). HMAC-SHA-1 should not be used in new designs, or when there's a choice. Bare SHA-1 must not be used in new designs, and should only be used when there's no other option, and a careful analysis concludes collision attacks, including with chosen prefix, are a non-issue.